# Neo4j is saving 3 GB CSV data as 25 GB

Tags: neo4j, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file that is 3GB in size and has 5 integer fields. When I load this data into neo4j with each row as nodes having 5 integer attributes, it is consuming 25GB. Is this normal behaviour for this database ?. I have not created any relationships yet, just loaded the rows to nodes.

Any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: I don't feel qualified to answer this question, but you might like to include more information in your question, especially the operating system and the exact Neo4j version. Also, there are a few CSV loaders - which one are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by this page [Neo4j’s Hardware Requirements](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator/)

it is OK, to have huge overhead for Integers, as:

*Nodes occupy 15B of space, relationships occupy 31B of space and properties occupy 41B of space.*